Sprite Renderer tile from pivot
In Unity I have a Sprite Renderer set to tiled draw mode.
The import settings look like this (custom pivot, custom borders):

I'd like to reposition the renderer object dynamically (in the OnValidate method) so that no matter what the tiled size is, the renderer stays in position relative to its parent and the pivot set in the import settings like this:

This is the closest I've got to the solution:
float spriteWorldHeight = groundRenderer.sprite.bounds.size.y;
float rendererHeight = groundRenderer.size.y;

float diff = rendererHeight - spriteWorldHeight;

//Getting the normalized pivot set in the import settings
float pivotY = groundRenderer.sprite.pivot.y / groundRenderer.sprite.rect.height;

float y = diff * (0.5f - pivotY);

groundRenderer.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, y);

Seems logical to me and it almost produces the desired result but there's a slight shift in the offset as I increase the height of the renderer.

What have you tried? Why don't you show us your code?

You're right, edited the post with the code I've tried.
